# How do I display a babylon.js animation on a Raspberry Pi 4b screen using ROS?

Tags: ros, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to run ROS in a multiple machine setup where my laptop is the master and an RPI is the slave. I want to run the babylon.js code on the RPI to display an animation. I am new to ROS and would like some guidance around this space on how I can achieve it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.